# jquery dynamically loaded page

Tags: jquery

I have a page index.php and I load jquery and use it. On this page i'm calling many ajax scripts to load content. This content will use jquery.

Given there are so many options for content I and that I want to use jquery on the loaded content how can I use jquery on dynamically loaded content.

Starting with a on ready call.

```
    <script>
$(document).on.(ready, function(){


    $.ajax({url: "myurl/<?php echo $mID; ?>/<?php echo $Code; ?>", success: function(result){
                /*$("#silver1").hide().show(250).html(result);*/
    }});

)}; 
</script
```

>

Comment: So... Is this the question or are you just saying that you are using `.on` method for dynamic content?

Comment: Give more details on what you want to do or what you have tried

Comment: updated the post, error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Comment: There shouldn't be a `.` after `on` and before `(ready...`  There's your unexpected token.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.on` for the dynamically created elements. Like:
Let's say you have a dyanamic created element with id `dynamicId`, then:

```
$("#dynamicId").on('click', function(){
    // do something here
})
```

Or you can add in HTML attribute like this:

```
<p id="someId" class="someClass" onclick="myFunction(this)">paragraph content</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to load the content to some container in index.php. For example:

```
<html><body><a href="test.php"></a><div id="pageContent"></div></body></html>
```

Then you load the content from the requested url with jQuery and put it in the container

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get( $(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
           $("#pageContent").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that this will override all functionalities in <a> tags. If you need more specific you should use CSS class selector for links that should load dynamic data.

Comment: But my container in index.php calls the page via ajax. Once the page is displayed I want it to do this using jquery. Using the original link in index.php won't work

Comment: It should work if you use .on() - it will also register the listener to dynamically loaded content

Answer (score 0):

using the function `.load()` like this `$('#contentAreaId').load('pagename');`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnLoad1.button').click(function() {
            $('#load_content').load('loadContent1.htm');
        });
        $('#btnLoad2.button').click(function() {
            $('#load_content').load('loadContent2.htm');
        });
    });
</script>
```